# Where to redirect UX career related questions

Tags: discussion

Once in a while, we get folks new to UX asking career and education related questions.

e.g. [New to UX. Should I focus on Web Design or UX in general?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/81470/new-to-ux-should-i-focus-on-web-design-or-ux-in-general)

Stack Exchange is a clearly not a good place to answer these, and we close the questions.

However, to me it's wonderful that people are interested in UX and we should encourage learning. Having the question closed with a "this is too opinion-based" doesn't help open the field up.

I think in the past, there's been some attempts to direct people to say the chatroom, but the UX chatroom isn't active enough to accommodate this.

So where should these people be directed to? Quora?

Comment: I think that's not a great question, but not necessarily because it talks about careers. It's just way too broad and lacking all context. On the other hand, I do think specific UX Career questions should be asked here.

Comment: Yes, the example provided is especially vague. I guess I should be more specific in naming it as UX career advice type questions. Questions like "How do you break into UX? Is doing a UX program the only way? How do you prove you have the relevant skill set?" Still seems too opinions based to me.

Comment: Maybe the workplace.stackexchange site?

Answer (score 1):

At this site we have tags for [career](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career) and [career-development](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-development). The [career](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career) tag has 13 questions where 7 are closed. We could interpret these scores as career specific questions doesn't really fit UX.SE. I think John's suggestion to take a look at [workplace.stackexchange](http://workplace.stackexchange.com) is a good place to start.

In any case you should look at job advertisements (Such as [Careers.SO](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/)) and see what companies really are after. And when you get a job, continue to subscribe to job ads just to make sure your standard isn't slipping away and that you don't keep up with the market. I've been doing this for 15 years now.

And don't forget to update your [Linked In](https://www.linkedin.com/) profile frequently.